# Mod_rewrite not Behaving as Expected

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to create a rewrite rule so that

```
www.example.com/whatever/here
```

Would map to

```
www.example.com/index.php/whatever/here
```

So that `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` is available. For that, I have created the following ruleset:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond {%REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond {%REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Only this gives me a 500 server error. The Apache error log states that

> [Sun Sep 30 17:23:08.758705 2012] [core:error] [pid 2584:tid 1704]
>   [client ::1:58591] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal
>   redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

But I fail to see the recursion. When I try it with, let's say a query:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1
```

It works as expected, but `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` is not available.

---

Also, before anyone asks, I want `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` because that way, I can have complicated paths like so:

```
www.example.com/controller/action/data?more=data
```

if I require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server environment variables are specified incorrectly in the `RewriteCond`, if that is your real code. If not a flat out 500 parse error, this would cause the conditions to be ignored and the rewrite to take place on every request causing a loop.

```
RewriteEngine On
# The % goes outside the {}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# And add a [L] flag
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew it was something silly, this works perfectly. Thanks a lot :)